# In Linux, what are these elf.h objects?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, executable, elf

From elf.h in c (Linux):

```
#include <elf.h>
```

What do the following pointers stand for/do? I tried looking up the documentation but there is nothing written about it. I just saw some source code from other people using it to implement an ELF loader:

```
Elf32_Ehdr
Elf32_Phdr
Elf32_Shdr
Elf32_Sym
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just structs with a bunch of information. For example, Elf32_Ehdr is defined as such:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char   e_ident[EI_NIDENT]; /* ident bytes */
    Elf32_Half  e_type;         /* file type */
    Elf32_Half  e_machine;      /* target machine */
    Elf32_Word  e_version;      /* file version */
    Elf32_Addr  e_entry;        /* start address */
    Elf32_Off   e_phoff;        /* phdr file offset */
    Elf32_Off   e_shoff;        /* shdr file offset */
    Elf32_Word  e_flags;        /* file flags */
    Elf32_Half  e_ehsize;       /* sizeof ehdr */
    Elf32_Half  e_phentsize;        /* sizeof phdr */
    Elf32_Half  e_phnum;        /* number phdrs */
    Elf32_Half  e_shentsize;        /* sizeof shdr */
    Elf32_Half  e_shnum;        /* number shdrs */
    Elf32_Half  e_shstrndx;     /* shdr string index */
} Elf32_Ehdr;
```

You can find all of them defined here:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-78/sys/elf.h

Answer (score 1):

ELF is a very general format for binary files (e.g. executables, core dumps). You can read [its specification](http://downloads.openwatcom.org/ftp/devel/docs/elf-64-gen.pdf) as linked from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

After you understand what the format looks like, you'll know about the ELF header, program headers, section headers, and much more. The `elf.h` header file defines C structures which match those parts of the ELF structure. You can use those to write your own ELF files or load existing ones.

tl;dr: If you don't want to write your own binary executable files or parse core dumps manually, you don't need to know this.